# Change date in the report to language Spanish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I have applicaction C# asp net MVC posted on a server, the server this in Spanish but show the date in the report(Crystal report) in english..

How can I show it in Spanish?

[image]

**the date of above is "Date of the data (crystal report)" and 
the other two dates below are you enter the application**

PD: Its important to mention my pc this in Spanish and so the date this in Spanish  when I change my pc a English the date change English.

Comment: You could hard-code it to use the Spanish culture in the format. Please show the code you're using to format the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the class [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2), which enables you to specify any language and styles for a language and/or a country. You can read about the .NET supported cultures [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx). In this case, you simply should convert your date to a string with the version of `ToString()` that takes a `CultureInfo` as a parameter. You can create this culture in your code, or access the default culture (the default is your computer's language, but in ASP.NET, you can keep a special culture for each user). Here's an example:

```
using System.Globalization;

// ...

yourDate.ToString(new CultureInfo("es-ES")); // Convert the date to a normal date string with Spain's Spanish culture
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hard-code a `CultureInfo` for `Spain` (or whatever country you like) and then pass that to the `ToString()` method of your `DateTime` object. Note that I also use it to get the "LongDatePattern" for that culture, but you can specify your own custom pattern if you want.:

```
var date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 28);

var englishUSCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var spanishSpainCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

Console.WriteLine("English-US long date ".PadRight(27, '.') + " " +
    date.ToString(englishUSCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern), 
    englishUSCulture);

Console.WriteLine("Spanish-Spain long date ".PadRight(27, '.') + " " +
    date.ToString(spanishSpainCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, 
    spanishSpainCulture));
```

**Ouput**

[image: ![![enter image description here]